# Invalid argument from bash script on MacOS command line

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run the LiteCart bash installer script located here:

https://github.com/litecart/installer/tree/master/cli

Unfortunately, it's giving me a problem when I add preset arguments like this:

```
             --document_root=/var/www/litecart/public_html \
             --db_server=localhost \
             --db_user=johndoe \
             --db_password=mycatsname \
             --db_database=mylitecartdb \
             --db_prefix=lc_ \
             --timezone=Europe/London \
             --admin_folder=admin \
             --admin_user=admin \
             --admin_password=mydogsname \
             --development_type=standard
```

I keep getting:

> Error: Invalid argument (--document_root=/var/www/litecart/public_html)

My computer is running MacOS 10.15 and the server is running CentOS 7.9.  The script runs fine without the arguments.

I can't find anything that even resembles this situation here.  What's the proper way to run a script like this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script contains no `case` for `--document_root`.

Try:

```
export document_root="/var/www/litecart/public_html"

./install.sh --db_server=localhost \
             --db_user=johndoe \
             --db_password=mycatsname \
             --db_database=mylitecartdb \
             --db_prefix=lc_
```

I assume that there are more problems in the script.